# Azure - how private static IP works from OS perspective?

Tags: windows, azure, dhcp, azure-networking

I am trying to find out what is the exact process of obtaining a static IP address (and DNS as well) from OS perspective.
Let's assume that we have a VM with assigned private static IP 10.10.10.10, when I will log in via RDP to this machine and check network options I found nothing that could mean static configuration.

The result of my thinking: OS thinks that it uses DHCP to obtain network configuration, but Azure is providing static configuration. If it is right, do anyone know how this process looks like? I didn't found such things in official documentation (I hope I did not miss it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your VM's in Azure use DHCP to obtain their IP addresses, and you should not make any changes to the network configuration inside the VM as this will likely break access to the VM.

When you assign a static private IP to a VM you are essentially creating a reservation in the Azure DHCP system which will ensure that this IP is always assigned to this VM.

Comment: Thanks for explanation! This is what I felt, but I wanted a clarification for that :)